# Complex analysis prerequisites for Silverman's The Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves

Tags: complex-analysis, elliptic-curves

I would like to take a course on elliptic curves using Silverman's *The Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves* next year. I would be taking complex analysis concurrently, but it was listed as a formal prerequisite, so I was planning to learn some complex analysis beforehand. What topics from complex analysis (esp. chapters from Stein's book) would I need to know to do elliptic curves over $\mathbb{C}$?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are referring to Stein's Complex Analysis (Princeton Lectures in Analysis, vol 2) by Elias M. Stein, Rami Shakarchi, then I'd suggest the following chapters/topics:

- Chapter 1: Preliminaries to Complex Analysis
- Chapter 2: Cauchy's Theorem
- Chapter 3: Meromorphic Functions and the Logarithm
- Chapter 5: Entire Functions
- Chapter 6: The Gamma and Zeta Functions
- Chapter 7: The Zeta Function and Prime Number Theorem
- Chapter 9: An Introduction to Elliptic Functions

Answer (score 3):

To begin on this topic I highly recommend Lectures on Elliptic Curves, J. W. S. Cassels. London Mathematical Society. Student Texts 24. This book of Professor Cassels  is indeed bright and decorated with a truly extraordinary didactic sense. You can get it free by internet.

Comment: It isn't clear to me how this answers the OP's question about the complex analysis needed for elliptic curves, but maybe I am missing something. Does Cassels's book contain the requisite complex analysis?

Comment: @J W:  Elliptic curves (e.c) involved many branches of mathematics.Respecting complex variables there is mainly the identification of the e.c. defined over $\mathbb C$ with a complex torus via an analytical isomorphism  (also there is the complex multiplication). All point is showed by professor Cassels with a very good didactic.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I am aware of the points you mention regarding complex variables and elliptic curves, but didn't know whether they were treated in Cassels's book.